# Why does Node seemingly wait for all Promises to resolve?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to JavaScript and NodeJS so forgive me if this question is rudimentary.

Let's say I just have a simple file `hello.js` and I run it with `$ node hello.js` and all this file contains is

```js
setTimeout(() => {console.log('hello');}, 5000);
```

Why doesn't this program finish immediately? Why instead does it wait for the underlying Promise to resolve?

After all, isn't the Promise associated with `setTimeout` created and run asynchronously? So wouldn't the main 'thread' of execution "fall off" when it encounters no more code to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Node event loop keeps running until all outstanding tasks are completed or cancelled.

`setTimeout` creates a pending event, so the loop will keep running until that executes.

Outstanding Promises, `setInterval` and other mechanisms can all prevent the event loop from halting.

It's worth noting that `setTimeout` does not use a promise at all. That's just a regular callback function. The `setTimeout()` API long predates Promises.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's more to the story/explanation here so I'll add an answer that contains additional info.

Nodejs keeps a reference counter for all unfinished asynchronous operations and nodejs itself will not exit automatically until all the asynchronous operations are complete (until the reference count gets to zero).  If you want nodejs to exit before that, you can call `process.exit()` whenever you want.

Since `setTimeout()` is an asynchronous operation, it contributes to the reference count of unfinished asynchronous operations and thus it keeps nodejs from automatically exiting until the timer fires.

Note that `setTimeout()` does not use a promise - it's just a plain callback.  It is not promises that nodejs waits for.  It is the underlying asynchronous operations that promises often are attached to that it actually waits for.

So, if you did just this:

```
 const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("did nothing here");
 });
```

Then, nodejs would not wait for that promise all by itself, even though that promise never resolves or rejects.  This is because nodejs does not actually wait for promises.  It waits for the underlying asynchronous operations that are usually behind promises.  Since there is no such underlying asynchronous operation behind this promise, nodejs does not wait for it.

---

It's also worth mentioning that you can actually tell nodejs to NOT wait for some asynchronous operations by using the [`.unref()` method](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_timeout_unref).  In the example you show, if you do this:

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => {console.log('hello');}, 5000);
timer.unref();
```

Then, nodejs will NOT wait for that timer before exiting and if this is your entire program, nodejs will actually exit immediately without waiting for the timer to fire.

As an example, I have a nodejs program that carries out some nightly maintenance using a recurring timer.  I don't want that maintenance timer to keep the nodejs program running if the other things that it's doing are done.  So, after I set the timer, I call the `.unref()` method on it.